# Video aspect ratio changes automatically on the firefox web browser

Tags: javascript, web, firefox, webcam

I'm working on a project, I'm accessing the camera using javascript and the aspect ratio of the camera is working fine on CHROME but when I'm testing it on the Firefox browser it changes the aspect ratio automatically

### this is a CHROME result
[image: chrome result]

and FIREFOX result
[image]

and my code
`<video id="video" width="280px" height="480px"></video>`

```js
const videoElement = document.getElementById("video");
const camera = new Camera(videoElement, {
  onFrame: async () => {
    await model.send({ image: videoElement });
  },
  width: 280,
  height: 480,
});
camera.start();
```

let me know if anyone can help with this

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the CSS aspect-ratio property? Not sure if this makes sense in your case, just a thought. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

Comment: I've added my own CSS but still not getting results

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

-I've got the answer in my video id I just need to add this CSS property
`object-fit: cover`